# Where should I set the authorization header after create the token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, authorization, request-headers

I am triying to implement a securuty system based on tokens. The problem is that I dont know where I must set the authorization header after create it in order to check it in all of my diferent routes. My code is the next.
I want to do it WITHOUT USING POSTMAN or any program like that.

This is the route for user login, where I create the token

```
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    const user = req.body.user;
    const token = jwt.sign({user},'secret_key');// generamos un identificador para el usuario que acaba de registrarse
    res.json({
        token
    });
});
```

Then, I have this route to test it works

```
router.get('/protected',ensureToken,(req,res)=>{
    jwt.verify(req.token,'secret_key',(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }else{
            res.json({
                text:'protected'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And finally, this is the middleware

```
function ensureToken(req,res,next){
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(bearerHeader);
    if(typeof bearerHeader != 'undefined'){
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
        const bearerToken= bearer[1];
        req.token = bearerToken; //almacenamos el token en el objeto de la peticion
        next();
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(403);//status de no permitido
    }
}
```

Where I should set the authorization header for all of my routes type 'get' as the protected route?

Comment: In my case, I set the jwt in header['x-access-token'] to authenticate the user. In backend, 
you can use middleware to verify for protected endpoints

Comment: But once I have created the token where should I set the header in order to check it later with a middleware?

Comment: 1. Login API response with token
2. Client store it wherever (like, redux, cookie, local storage, etc)
3. When client request private API, set header property with token in this case let it be x-access-token
4. Since token decoding logic is same for any protected endpoints, make an express middleware.
5. In middleware, decode the token and if it is not expired and have access grant, set the additional value in request if it's needed (ex> req.user = decoded)
6. Access to the user data in API router and do whatever you want

Comment: When you say "2.Client store it wherever", Can I store it in a post route? I mean, I receive data from a form in a post route (router.post(/login) for example), is in this site where I should assign the value to the header or to the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

#### Verifying

```js
router.get('/verify', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers['x-access-token']//client should this value

        if (!token){
            return res.status(401).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Unauthorized request',
            })
        }
        else if (isExpiredToken(token)){
            return res.status(300).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Token is expired',
            })
        }

        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY)

        const expiredAt = moment.unix(decoded.exp).subtract(@YOUR_EXPIRED_TIME, 'minutes')
        const now = moment()

        let newToken = null

        if (now.isAfter(expiredAt)) {//refresh the token
            const userFromDB = await User.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: decoded.id,
                },
            })

            const content = util.sanitize(userFromDB)

            newToken = await jwt.sign(content, SECRET_KEY, {
                audience: content.email,
                issuer: 'YOUR_APP',
                expiresIn: 'YOUR_EXPIRED_TIME',
            })

            console.log(
                `VERIFY\tToken refreshed automatically for user-${content.id}`
            )
        }

        res.send({
            success: true,
            nextToken: newToken,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)

        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Internal server error',
        })
    }
})
```

#### Middleware

```js
 async function authMiddleware(req, res, next){
   /* In this case, user can authenticate with header['x-access-token'] or body['accessToken']*/
   const token = req.header['x-access-token'] || req.body['accessToken'] || undefined

   if(!token) return res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'unauthorized' })

   try{
     const user = await jwt.verify(token, secret)
     req.user = { ...user }
     return next()
   }
   catch(e){
     console.log(e)
     return res.status(500).send({ success : false, message : 'internal server error' })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of code where the cliente set the header after creating the token please?